# Query results are not correct in C#.NET with SQLite database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have an application implemented in C#.NET and SQLite database. I need to count some values of a columns (status) of database table (fruit). The table is like following.

```
Id  B   M   status
1   10  101 2
2   11  102 2
3   11  103 0
4   12  104 2
5   13  105 2
6   13  105 2
7   14  106 2
8   14  106 2
9   14  106 2
10  14  106 2
```

I have used following methods to extract the values from the table and show output.

```
public void CountingValues()
        {    
        string strA, strB, strC;
        double Total;            

        strA = countA();
        strB = countB();
        strC = countC();    

        MessageBox.Show(strA.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(strB.ToString()); 
        MessageBox.Show(strC.ToString());

}
    public string countA() 
    {
        return GetData("SELECT COUNT(status) FROM fruit WHERE status = 2;");
    }
    public string countB()
    {
        return GetData("SELECT COUNT(status) FROM fruit WHERE status = 1;");
    }
    public string countC()
    {
        return GetData("SELECT COUNT(status) FROM fruit WHERE status = 0;");
    }


    private String GetData(String cmd)
    {
        String result = "";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
        command.CommandText = cmd;
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result = reader[0].ToString();                
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
```

The results of strA, strB and strC should be 9, 0, and 1 respectively. But, it is showing 4, 0, and 6.
Could anyone tell me please what is wrong here ?

Comment: I suggest you use an alternative query to display the contents of the database as read by .NET. My guess is that you're accidentally attaching to the wrong database.

Comment: my database is uploaded when application is running. so, there is no possibilities of wrong database connection. and, which alternative query you are talking about ? could you please explain ?

Comment: I'm suggesting dumping the results of `SELECT * FROM fruit` for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: I used SELECT * FROM fruit where status = 2. but it is showing same result.

Comment: Well you'd need to change the rest of the code, to read all the columns, and all the rows...

Comment: do you find anything wrong with the above code that i used ?

Comment: Nothing desperately obvious, which is why I was suggesting other diagnostics. It's not how I would write the code, but it's not obvious why it would behave that way.

Comment: I used the method given in the below answer section which uses DataTable. But, it is showing same results. :(

Comment: /me digging the grave. Were you able to find out what was going on ? I have a similar problem where SQLiteBrowser yield a result and the C# is yielding another result. Worst than that, it does not always show the same data...

Answer (score 1):

Try using select count(*) instead of select count(status).. Also if you are using visual studio put a breakpoint on the "result = reader[0].ToString()" and see what value is being populated.

Anytime i do database debugging I check to make sure the datatable is the same as what i would expect to receive from the sql query. put a breakpoint on return dt and make sure that you get the same datatable result as if you were to just execute this query on the db. Make sure you change the sqlconnection object to the type you are using.

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarManConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
     conn.Open();
     string query = "SELECT count(*) from fruit where status = 2";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
     return dt;
}
```

Comment: it will need to convert the data from DataTable to String or double, since it returns dt (DataTable). Am i right ?

Comment: it is showing error- unable to cast object of type 'System.data.datatable' to type 'system.IConvertible'.

Comment: is there any other option than using DataTable for counting the values ?

Comment: I used your method using DataTable, but it is showing same result.

Comment: in order to grab the value from the tdatatable you wll have to do "dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()", and you dont need to count any values, you have already returned the count in that datatable object

Comment: yes, i have done exactly the same as you said. But, the result is still same. no change. i can't find any clue what's wrong there :(

Comment: according to your table, select count(*) from fruit where status = 2 should be returning 9, what result do you get when you execute that same query on the database? using an sql query

Comment: you are right. i should get 9 from the query, but i am getting 4. 4, 0, 6 instead of 9, 0, 1. can you give me any clue what can be done ?

Comment: check to make sure you are connecting to the proper database, it seems as if you have everything working correctly you are just executing on the wrong data.

Comment: it is a SQLite database. database is uploaded when application is running. so, connecting to wrong database is not possible.